# How to maintain memory efficiency in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, memory-management, garbage-collection

I have a dataset which have a text data column ,there are about **600k** of rows

so I am trying to save only text data into **H5** format for future faster loading ,I tried using Garbage collecter

this is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import gc

df = pd.read_csv('Reviews.csv')

text = df['Text']

df = None
gc.collect()

text.to_hdf('text.h5','data',format='table')
text = None
gc.collect()


print("Done")
```

But unfortunately this is giving **Memory Error** even though I have **16gb** of memory,how can I do this without giving up on memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- read your big `csv` file *in chunks* (adjust `chunksize` empirically)
- append a chunk (set of rows) into specified HDFStore with `append=True` mode

---

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv('Reviews.csv', chunksize=10**5):
    chunk['Text'].to_hdf('text.h5', 'data', format='table', append=True)
```